# Non-latin image broken

Tags: php, html, azure, apache

I'm developing web app for my customer. He uploaded image with name 'Şahan.png'

On my test server I can see image properly.

```
<img src="https://example.com/Şahan.png">
```

But on my production environment which is hosting on azure, image looks like broken.

[image]

Comment: Where is the image stored? Is it stored in Azure Blob Storage? Can you share the actual URL?

Comment: No, its inside my wwwroot folder

Comment: Ok. What happens when you put the image URL in browser's address bar? Does the image gets displayed? If not, what's the error you get (404 etc.)?

Comment: On test server I can see image, but on production its give me 404 error

Comment: I would recommend connecting to your production web server using kudu console to verify the image is indeed there.

Comment: Follow GauravMantri's suggestion, you can visit scm site.  `https://yourapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui`.

Answer (score 0):

Print `F12`, check `img` tag. After test, in linux or windows, it all works fine on azure.

[image]

## Please try to open your kudu site, and check your `Şahan.png` file.

[image]